# Appending to the top of a div without messing scroll status in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, infinite-scroll

I'm having a problem in react. I'm trying to implement a simple scrollable div which contains a lot of children divs, which are viewable by horizontal scrolling.

Basically each children div correspond to a day. A user loads the component the first time viewing the information about the current day and a few next days. However if the users scrolls (either left or right) I want to be able to append more info, achieving a sort of "infinite scroll feature".

When I try to append new children divs at the end of the parent div I've no problems at all. However when I try to append new children at the start of the parent div (ex. the users wants to see previous days), upon adding the new elements the scroll changes resulting in the users being confused on why the scroll changed.

I've created a small JS fiddle to replicate my setup. Try clicking on "add left" and you will see the current behavior.
Is there any way to add a new element without shifting the whole view?
https://jsfiddle.net/k75pvey3/3/

P.s. I've seen many answers online to this problem. However all of the ones I've seen where assuming the new component had a specific width. In my case (as I'm trying to show in the fiddle) I've no way to determine which will be the width of the newly added children div.

For reference here is the code:

```
function App(props) {

  const [array, setArray] = React.useState(['100', '321', '32', '412', '12', '33', '54'])

  const addLeft = () => {
    setArray([Math.floor(Math.random()*300), ...array]) 
  }
  
  const addRight = () => {
    setArray([...array, Math.floor(Math.random()*300)]) 
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={addLeft}>add left</button>
      <button onClick={addRight}>add right</button>
      <div className="container">
        {array.map(i => (<div className="element" style={{minWidth:i}}>{i}</div>))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

and here is the css:

```
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 550px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.element {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a bad news for you, this is generally one of the complicated part about virtual list - adding a new element at the beginning of the scroll axis while maintaining scroll position.

It is generally recommended for you to use existing solutions out there such as [`react-virtualized`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized) or [`react-window`](https://react-window.vercel.app/).

If you don't want to use an existing library, one solution is you can listen to the `width` of the contents inside the `div` (eg. [`Element.scrollWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth)), then compensate it by setting the [`.scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) value of the container. However, it gets complicated when you load when scrolling as the scroll can be "with intertia" especially on touch-screen devices / touchpad on laptops.

*(Speaking from experience when I am over-confident I can write a virtual list myself, ends up using a library instead because of lots of edge cases)*

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast reply, I looked into scrollLeft and got a somewhat working thing. However it was very sketchy and laggy. That's why I decided to ask it as a question here.

Regarding the library, I'm not completely against using them (usually I'm pro, but in this case the component is very complex, I might need to rewrite it completely). I will look into this react-virtualized

Comment: Do you maybe have an example code that uses react-window for infinite scrolling in both directions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ref` to get control on the parent.

Then on adding an element, use [`ref.current.scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollBy) to scroll the amount of pixels needed.

You could use another ref to get the actual width of the added element, but in your example, we can just use that random number

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function App(props) {

    const prnt = useRef();

  const [array, setArray] = React.useState(['100', '321', '32', '412', '12', '33', '54'])

  const addLeft = () => {
    const newWidth = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    setArray([ newWidth, ...array]) 
    prnt.current.scrollBy(newWidth - 20, 0)
  }
  
  const addRight = () => {
    setArray([...array, Math.floor(Math.random()*300)]) 
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={addLeft}>add left</button>
      <button onClick={addRight}>add right</button>
      <div className="container" ref={prnt}>
        {array.map(i => (<div className="element" style={{minWidth:i}}>{i}</div>))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
body {
  background: transparent; /* Make it white if you need */
  padding: 0 24px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.App {
  color: #72a24d;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 550px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.element {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```